# Any New (not low end) phones using Froyo (or Froyo-style software system)?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, device-firmware, themes

Considering the bugs I've heard about the newer Androids (battery life, GPS and distance etc), and the fact that Froyo/gingerbread have better menu systems (larger, with text, not a toolbar), as well as more hardware buttons, 8 recent apps shown in the hold-home listing instead of 2 or 3... I was wondering if there are any modern phones with 2.2 or 2.3-based ROMs?

The problem is, with this old of a phone (or new one, they still sell 2.2/2.3 phones in stores) you shouldn't use the default browser, it has many known security vulnerabilities.

Considering the open source nature of it, I would be surprised to hear there is not a Froyo-skin or a version of Froyo with updated API.

Answer (score 1):

Thing is, if a manufacturer would decide bringing a new phone on the market with such an old system, he'd get no license to pre-install any Google apps. Either your device runs an up-to-date Android version (I don't remember the details completely on what's counted here as "up-to-date", whether it were the latest two versions, or a version "not older than x months" – but Froyo is definitely out, as is Gingerbread, and IMHO even ICS) – or no Google Apps. As a device without *Google Play* pre-installed isn't that big selling hit for most people, manufacturers want the *GApps* shipping with their device. That doesn't leave much choice.

So it's pretty unlikely you will find a device with up-to-date hardware running Froyo or Gingerbread.

This doesn't keep modders from "skinning" the look-and-feel, sure. And many things can modified that way. Though I've never heard/read from any modification in this direction, you might find some "ROM kitchen" or the like offering it.